# Spherical Harmonics - Inner product

Tags: spherical-harmonics

If $\mathcal{P}$ is space of polynomials in $n$ variables with complex coefficients. Let $\mathcal{P_m}$ be the subspace of homogeneous polynomials of degree m. How would i show that for two polynomials
$$p(x) = \sum_{\alpha} a_\alpha x^\alpha, q(x) = \sum_{\alpha}b_\alpha x^\alpha,\quad x^{\alpha} = x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n} $$
with $\alpha_1 +\cdots + \alpha_n = m$.  The inner product defined as

$$\langle p, q\rangle = \left(p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\overline{q}\right) (0)  \qquad \qquad \ \qquad \ \qquad (1) $$
is equal to

$$\langle p, q\rangle  \sum_\alpha \alpha! a_\alpha \overline{b_\alpha} $$

where $\alpha! = \alpha_1!\cdots\alpha_n!$.

I see that in equation (1), that since we evaluate in "$0$" all the variables term disappear, so we only have a product of the constant terms.
My attempt would be something like

\begin{align}
\langle p,q \rangle &= \sum_\alpha a_\alpha\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)^\alpha \sum_\alpha \overline{b_\alpha x^\alpha} (0) \\
&=  \sum_\alpha a_\alpha \left( \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial x_1\cdots \partial x_n }\right) \sum_{\alpha} \overline{b_\alpha x^\alpha} (0) 
\end{align}
how would i get $\alpha!$ out of this??

Comment: Prove that $\partial^\alpha(x^\alpha)=\alpha!$, and that $\partial^\alpha(x^\beta)(0)=0$ for $\beta\not=\alpha$...

Comment: Nice! Just to be clear, for $\beta \neq \alpha$ So if $\beta < \alpha$ all variables "vanishes", and if $\beta > \alpha$ there would remains some variables of $x$, but when we evaluate them at $(0)$ they disappear right ?

Comment: Well, that's the general idea, but it's slightly more subtle: if _any_ $\beta_j$ is not equal to the corresponding $\alpha_j$, then that causes the outcome to vanish. The partial order on multi-indices is not a "total" order.

Comment: Ah yes of course, that would be a better way to explain it, thanks! :)